# Exception for request->all()

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a form with over 50 fields. Data in these fields go into a database table.
Something like this:

```
$something=new something();       
$something->create($request->all());
```

In the meantime I realized that the value of one field needs to be concatenated with a string before inserting into the table.
How can I create an exception for `create($request->all());`  ?
I'm trying to avoid a situation similar to this:

```
$something->Name=Input::get('Name');
$something->Country=Input::get('Country');
$something->City=Input::get('City');
```

...because, as I said, I have a lot of fields to insert into the table.
Anyone can help me, please ?

Comment: Do whatever validation you need before you create?

Comment: sorry... it's not a validation, but rather a modification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, just put it in a variable and modify it.

For example something like:

```
$something=new something();
$r=$request->all();
$r['foo'] = $r['foo'] . 'bar';
$something->create($r);
```